# How to read names in file upto specific character using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
Group Name: grp1

name1
name2
name3

===============
Group Name: grp2

NAME4
NAME5
NAME6
NAME7
===============

and so on....
```

mainfile.txt will have above content, here i need to create lists with group names and each list will have its content which is present up to "=========" symbol.

For Eg: as per above file content i need to create two lists(which is grp1 and grp2) where my grp1
list will have its own "names" as a content, below for reference.

`grp1 = ['name1','name2',name3']`

`grp2 = ['NAME4','NAME5',NAME6', 'NAME7']`

Can any one help me achieve this using python?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate on your file line by line like and check if the content is equal to the separator. This would give you something like this:

```
file = open("myfile.txt", "r+")
line = file.readline()
groups = []

while line:
    group = []
    while line and line != "===============":
        group.append(line)
        line = file.readline()
    groups.append(group)
    line = file.readline()
```

edit: I guess you should also add a condition to ignore blank lines and the one with the group name.